# PL/pgSQL restart generated sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, plpgsql, spring-data-r2dbc

I have an initialization script I use on Spring Boot application start and I create the table if it doesn't exist. Then I delete all the data from the table and execute a bunch on inserts.

```
create table if not exists employee (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar(255)
);

delete from employee;

-- inserts
```

With each execution of the script, the sequence still continues, so the new rows don't start from one. I have to reset such sequence too, however, it is generated and I dont know its name unless I call this script:

```
select pg_get_serial_sequence('employee', 'id');
-- returns public.employee_id_seq
```

I tried to combine it together and reset the sequence based on the output of this funciton, but with no luck. How to reset the generated sequence without knowing its name? My attempt so far cannot resolve the `seq` sequence from the variable:

```
do $$
    declare
        seq varchar(255);
    begin
        select pg_get_serial_sequence('employee', 'employee_id') into seq;
        alter sequence seq restart with 1;
end; $$;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use [`truncate table . . . restart identity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html) instead of `delete`:

```
truncate table employee restart identity;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0abd203db70ab6dab87de028f9481b9e) is a db<>fiddle.

`Truncate table` is recommended for other reasons too.  For instance, it reclaims the space the table used immediately.  And it is much faster.  The one difference is that `delete` triggers are not called (although your table doesn't have any triggers).

Answer (score 1):

It is basically a bad idea to reset a id serial to any number, so you must be very carefully using the following.

especially when you have foreign keys to the id firld

the camand you are looking for is

```
ALTER SEQUENCE <table_name>_<id_column>_seq RESTART WITH 1
```

> ```
> create table if not exists employee (
>     id serial primary key,
>     name varchar(255)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO employee (name) VALUES ('a'),('B'),('C')
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> delete from employee;
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> ALTER SEQUENCE employee_id_seq RESTART WITH 1
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO employee (name) VALUES  ('a')
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM employee
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name
> -: | :---
>  1 | a
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a05d0078e378f993cd655c043a548ed1)*

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. I am aware of the consequences of resetting the sequence. Does PostgreSQL assure that the generated pattern is always `<table_name>_<id_column>_seq`?

Comment: yes the pattern is always the same as described in my answer